# Couldn't access the parent library folder in child pom file?

Tags: maven, maven-3

How I could access parents lib folder jar file into child module pom file.

**Project Structure**

```
test
  |___ test 1
          |___ pom.xml
  |___ test 2
          |___ pom.xml
  |___ libs
          |___ test1-1.0.0.jar
  |___ pom.xml
```

**test2 pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <systemPath>${main.basedir}/libs/test1-1.0.0.jar</systemPath>
    <scope>system</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Error**

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for test:test2:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${main.basedir}/libs/test2-1.0.0.jar

Thank you

Comment: how have you defined main.basedir . Its not able to recognize main.basedir.

Comment: define it in main pom as :  <main.basedir>${project.basedir}</main.basedir>